# how to add values if same date repeats from json

Tags: java, android, html, json

I developing an android app with graph value. I'm struggling here. Server returns json object like this

```
[{
    "date": "01-03-2018",
    "value": "12",
    },
    {
    "id": "01-03-2018",
    "value": "8",
    },
    {
    "id": "02-03-2018",
    "value": "3",
    },
    {
    "id": "03-03-2018",
    "value": "5",
    },
    {
    "id": "03-03-2018",
    "value": "8",
    },
    {
    "id": "04-03-2018",
    "value": "21",
    }]
```

before adding to arraylist in android the json should be convert into like this

```
[{
    "date": "01-03-2018",
    "value": "20",
    },

    {
    "id": "02-03-2018",
    "value": "3",
    },
    {
    "id": "03-03-2018",
    "value": "13",
    },
    {
    "id": "04-03-2018",
    "value": "21",
    }]
```

please help me! thanks in advance

Comment: why you want to convert it into this json? instead add condition to check for not adding duplicate value in arraylist

Comment: add your code here if you don't understand

Comment: U can store The JSON array into a Set<CustomClass> this customClass will have a field id and Value and this class must implement equals and HashCode.

Comment: you have to just sort collection on your needs. specify what you want, how you need data to be sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to convert a JSON String to another JSON String.
Instead of that, you can either use ArrayList directly or HashMap for storing the data.

If you want to use HashMap then check below

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    JSONObject list = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String key = list.getString("date");
    if (!map.containsKey(key) {
        map.put(key, list.getInt("value");
    } else {
        int val = map.get(key) + list.getInt("value");
        map.put(key, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: The map doesn't maintain your sequence. if you don't need to maintain it. Then I suppose it is good.

Comment: @KushaalSingla If you want to maintain the sequence you can use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HahMap`.